# Translation of "要" in "我去要出租车"

Tags: translation

> "我去要出租车"

What is the meaning of "要" in this sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

要 has a meaning of "request", "ask for" etc.

Answer (score 4):

I'm chinese and I don't quite understand you sentence. My guess is that it is supposed to be

> 我去叫出租车 （I'm going to call a taxi）

Perhaps in some local tongue they use 要 and 叫 interchangeably in this occasion, but this is by no means standard.

Comment: I also thought that 叫 was missing.However, I saw this in a textbook, so I'm not so sure.........

Comment: I've been seeing a lot of "I'm a native chinese" lately. But I think it lacks some sort of additional info, like "I'm a native chinese from 什么地方", since chinese varies a lot from place to place.